# XmlPullParser skipping some tag

Tags: android, rss

I am trying to parse RSS with XmlPullParser pull parser in android but it keeps skipping the `content:encoded` tag in the first iteration and only gabs in it the second iteration although it grabs the previous tag data instead, here is my code

```
ArrayList<FeedItem> feeds = new ArrayList<>();

    String title = "";
    String description = "";
    String link = "";
    String encodedDesciption = "";
    String imgSrc = "image";
    boolean isItem = false;
    try {
        XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
        xmlPullParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        xmlPullParser.setInput(inputStream, null);

       // xmlPullParser.nextTag();
        while (xmlPullParser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();

            String name = xmlPullParser.getName();
            if(name == null)
                continue;

            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    isItem = false;
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    isItem = true;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            String result = "";
            if (xmlPullParser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                result = xmlPullParser.getText();
                xmlPullParser.nextTag();
            }

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)) {
                title = result;
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)) {
                link = result;
            } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION)) {
                description = result;
            }else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(DESCRIPTION_ENCODED)) {
                encodedDesciption = result;

            }


            if (title != null && link != null && description != null && imgSrc != null && encodedDesciption != null) {
                if(isItem) {
                    Document document = Jsoup.parse(encodedDesciption);
                    Element img = document.select("img").first();
                    if (img != null) {
                        imgSrc = img.attr("src");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Image found "+imgSrc);
                        img.remove();
                    }else  Log.d(TAG, "Image not found");
                    FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem(title, description, encodedDesciption, imgSrc, link );
                    feeds.add(feedItem);
                    Log.d(TAG, feedItem.toString());
                }

                title = null;
                link = null;
                description = null;
                isItem = false;
            }


        }


    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the RSS  [link](http://www.znbc.co.zm/?feed=rss2) I am parsing

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: I have removed the previous question, didnt get audience